# Does InfoPath 2013 support Managed Meta Data Column?

Tags: infopath, managed-metadata

Does InfoPath 2013 support Managed Meta Data Column? If not then any workaround to render the Managed Meta data columns?

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't. There are workarounds, but they're generally messy and involve either code or [calling](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/632190d9-663b-4ea6-82e8-5c1e7f2f57c5/managed-metadata-columns-infopath?forum=sharepointadminprevious) the SharePoint web services.